# how to use aws s3 service by soap

Tags: soap, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to use the AWS S3 by soap, i checked the aws website, there is an example to list all the bucket.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html. so when i use the soap template. it returns "405 Method Not Allowed". any help? thanks

this is what is sent to aws s3 server.

```
POST http://s3.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 497

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns="https://.s3.amazonaws.com/">
  <ListAllMyBuckets xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
  <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <Timestamp>2006-03-01T12:00:00.183Z</Timestamp>
  <Signature>Iuyz3d3P0aTou39dzbqaEXAMPLE=</Signature>
  </ListAllMyBuckets>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTPS, not HTTP.

> Note that SOAP requests, both authenticated and anonymous, must be sent to Amazon S3 using SSL. Amazon S3 returns an error when you send a SOAP request over HTTP.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APISoap.html

Note also that the SOAP interface is deprecated.

Comment: thanks Michael, but when i changed to https, the code in first line to "POST https://s3.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1". the AWS server still returns Method not Allowed.